# LTSpice: hand calculation vs simulation - GDS/ro value

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, ltspice, simulation

I've created my own PMOS/NMOS models (LEVEL 1) for test purposes. The DC results match with the theoretical values but there is a mistmatch regarding the output conductance.

Here is the testbench:

[image: testbench]

Here are the log resuts:

[image: logresults]

As I understand, the theoretical value for gds/ro is:

$$
r_O = {V_A\over I_D} = {1\over \lambda I_D}
$$

So, for M1:

$$
I_{M1} = 30.7uA
$$

$$
r_{o_{M1}-theory} = \frac{1}{\lambda I_{M1}} = \frac{1}{(0.04 V^{-1}) (30.7 \mu A)} = 814.33 K \Omega
$$

The value from simulation is:

$$
r_{o_{M1}-sim} = \frac{1}{gds_{M1}} = \frac{1}{1.08\mu \Omega^{-1}} = 925.92K\Omega
$$

Any clue on this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Go to LTspice help, search for "M" and find the MOSFET page. Read down to find that Level 1 is "Shichman-Hodges." Then go find their paper, [H. Shichman and D. A. Hodges. *"Modeling and simulation of insulated-gate field-effect transistor switching circuits,"* IEEE Journal of Solid-State Circuits, SC-3, 285, Sept. 1968](https://pages.jh.edu/aandreo1/216/Bibliography/Technology/Shichman_IEEE_Journal_of_Solid-State_Circuits_1968.pdf) and read it. Then come back with references to the paper itself and your (new) calculations.

Comment: It is also worth getting and reading [Andrei Vladimirescu's *"The SPICE Book"*](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0471609269), which you can find on the web in PDF form if you look. He's an author of the Level II model, as you will also see in the LTspice help page on MOSFETs.

Comment: There is a hidden lesson here: any simulation will only be as good as the models within. Therefore it is up to the user to verify that the models correspond to the expectations. In this case you assumed that the model would behave according to some formulas

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the Schichman-Hodges model (LEVEL 1) calculates the output resistance as:

$$
ro = \frac{1+\lambda V_{DS}}{\lambda I_{D}}
$$

This fit with the simulation results:

$$
ro = \frac{1+(0.04V^{-1})(3.411V)}{(0.04V^{-1}) (30.7 \mu A)} = 925.439 K\Omega
$$